# System Verilog Assertion bit vector

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I want assertion that if in current cycle signal 'a' equal to "0110"(in binary) in the next cycle signal'b'not bigger than 31(it should be between 0 and 31.it should be less than 00000000000000000000000000011111)(its width equal 32)
Can everyone help me to write assertion?!
Excuse me for my bad english.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. FYI in Verilog, 0110 is read as decimal one hundred and ten; `4'b0110` is read as binary ten

Answer (score 1):

```
assert property  ( @ (posedge clk )  (a == 32'b0110) |=> ( b > 32'd0 && b < 32'd32 ) );
```

assert - will set the property( assertion )  into action. The property has to be based on a clock . Choose the appropriate clock which is triggering the registers `a` & `b` in the design. Implication operator `|=>` indicates that the property has to be true in the next clock cycle. In this case if `a` equals 6, the next cycle `b` has to between 0 and 32 ).

In case of a failure some similar message ( based on the simulator ) will be displayed.

```
top.unnamed$$_0: started at  ns failed at  ns
    Offending '((b > 0) && (b < 32))'
```

You can read up a basic tutorial on assertions

https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/assertions/